# Почему nginx может обрезать контент файла?

Tags: nginx

Есть файл на сервере с таким содержимым:

```
00000
```

Делаю запрос к nginx:

```
GET /test2.js
```

На него такой ответ:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Cache-Control: max-age=315360000
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 5
Content-Type: application/javascript
Date: Tue, 14 May 2019 14:22:52 GMT
ETag: "5cdacf39-5"
Expires: Thu, 31 Dec 2037 23:55:55 GMT
Keep-Alive: timeout=60
Last-Modified: Tue, 14 May 2019 14:22:49 GMT
Server: nginx

00000
```

Далее файл изменяется:

```
1111111111
```

И на все тот же запрос получаю ответ:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Cache-Control: max-age=315360000
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 5
Content-Type: application/javascript
Date: Tue, 14 May 2019 14:23:10 GMT
ETag: "5cdacf11-5"
Expires: Thu, 31 Dec 2037 23:55:55 GMT
Keep-Alive: timeout=60
Last-Modified: Tue, 14 May 2019 14:22:09 GMT
Server: nginx

11111
```

То есть контент поменялся, но размер не изменился.

Если позже еще сделать запрос, то получаю ответ с правильной длиной:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Cache-Control: max-age=315360000
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 10
Content-Type: application/javascript
Date: Tue, 14 May 2019 14:23:17 GMT
ETag: "5cdacf46-a"
Expires: Thu, 31 Dec 2037 23:55:55 GMT
Keep-Alive: timeout=60
Last-Modified: Tue, 14 May 2019 14:23:02 GMT
Server: nginx

1111111111
```

Судя по Date и Last-Modified nginx какое-то время не знает, что файл изменился, но отдает новый контент при старом размере файла. Почему так может быть?

Comment: `nginx какое-то время не знает` -   Правильная настройка кеширования nginx поможет.

Comment: @NewView Подскажите, что может быть настроено неправильно? Используются стандартные конфиги VestaCP: [nginx.conf](https://github.com/serghey-rodin/vesta/blob/master/install/rhel/7/nginx/nginx.conf), [vhost](https://github.com/serghey-rodin/vesta/blob/master/install/rhel/7/templates/web/nginx/default.tpl)

Comment: В поиске никак? https://ruhighload.com/Кэширование+с+nginx , https://habr.com/ru/post/428127/

Comment: @NewView А как это поможет? Мне не нужно кэшировать ответы, я хочу, чтобы nginx отдавал правильный файл с правильной длиной.

Comment: Минимизируйте время валидности кеша, или отключите кеш для этого.

Comment: @NewView Вы какой кэш имеете ввиду? proxy_cache у меня не используется, есть только open_file_cache и похоже, что проблема как раз в нем.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Мне помогло выключение кэша открытых файлов:

```
open_file_cache off;
```

Answer (score 1):

Это очень старый и очень неочевидный кейс. Мне в своё время помогла директива `sendfile`:

```
location /video/ {
    sendfile off;
}
```

Попробуй её применить.

Comment: Мне `sendfile off;` не помогло, получилось исправить через `open_file_cache off;`.